# record video flex AIR app with media server

Tags: apache-flex, air, record, red5

is there a way to record video from a flex AIR2 app with media server and is there a free solution to that? I currently use RED5 with the installed oflademo app provided with that but the quality of the recorded video is awful..any suggestion or idea?

I publish with this way:

```
nc = new NetConnection();
nc.connect(mediaServerUrl); //rtmp:localhost:5080/oflaDemo
ns = new NetStream(nc); 
ns.attachCamera(cam);
ns.attachAudio(mic);
ns.publish( filename, "record" );
```

and when i want to play the video from the media server i do:

```
<s:VideoPlayer id="myVid" visible="true" width="100%" height="100%"
                       mediaPlayerStateChange="myVid_mediaPlayerStateChangeHandler(event)">
            <s:source>
                <s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource host="{mediaServerUrl}" streamType="recorded">
                    <s:DynamicStreamingVideoItem streamName="path_to_filename.flv"/>
                </s:DynamicStreamingVideoSource>
            </s:source>
        </s:VideoPlayer>
```

am i doing something wrong or is there any problem with the RED5 oflaDemo app?

i have set my cam like this:

```
cam.setMode(640, 480, 15);
cam.setQuality(65536,90);
```

Thanks a lot in advance...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have enough bandwidth to transmit a hi-quality video then lower the quality.
Else it'll stuck the first seconds.

I recommend you to check your bandwidth with the RED5 demo (bandwidth check).
Then adjust the quality according to your bandwidth:

```
cam.setQuality(bandwidth, quality);
```

Comment: Or just set a value for quality and pass 0 for bandwidth to let the client/server figure out how much bandwidth to use. Also, the docs say this is primarily for when you're using Flash Media Server, does Red5 support it?

Comment: yes it supports it..but the quality is not the preffered one!maybe there is something with the codecs..